# How many mcpe days does it take to make mossy stone?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know how to make mossy stone in mcpe. I also know it takes a very long time. But I have waited for weeks (real life) and nothing. How many mcpe days does it take?

Comment: I've voted to close this because it is about exploits.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ I've deleted that extra question. One post, one question. Besides, exploits are not off topic.

Comment: True. I thought we didn't support them though.

Comment: @Timtech We don't support piracy for legal reasons; you might be thinking of that. Many people strongly *object* to exploits in multiplayer games, especially MMOs, since using them is reprehensible, but I don't believe we have a *policy* against them. (You're just not likely to get help here.) Exploits in single-player games we definitely support, since we have a "it's your game, enjoy it how you like" community attitude.

Comment: I don't play mcpe multiplayer 'cause it lags like no ones business.

Comment: @Dark If you want to ask about exploits, ask it as a separate question (because it *is* a separate question). You'll notice it's been removed from here.

Comment: No. I KNOW how to get it. How many mcpe days must I let it set in water

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm glad we, umm, support exploits in games. Exploits cover cheats added to the game, like hacked clients and injectable mod packs?

Comment: @Timtech The difference between a "hacked client" and a "modded install" is not in the code used, it's in the wider context. We don't help people break their ToS (not legal) or circumvent DRM (not legal in many places), but we will help people void their hardware warrantee (perfectly legal in most places), even if all those involve the exact same "mod". The exact same change to a game can be called a "hack", "exploit", or "mod", depending on the context. Regardless, the only thing we don't help with is stuff that exposes the site to legal action, but some users draw their personal line harder.

Comment: I *knew* there was a duplicate, but I couldn't find it and started to think I'd imagined it!

Comment: @DarkStevie Who told you that letting it sit in water turns it mossy? That is, as I said, only a myth, but I'm curious where it comes from.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize I was "creating" a duplicate. I don't have much wifi access. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Are you in survival mode? It's only available in creative at this time:

> In Minecraft: Pocket Edition, Moss Stone is in Creative mode, but is unobtainable in Survival mode.

Source: [The Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Moss_Stone)

Answer (score 2):

Being able to make mossy cobblestone by "leaving it in water" or "burying it under sand" or somesuch is a persistent myth. You have been deceived.

Before version 0.9.0, the world doesn't ever generate mossy cobblestone, so you can't even obtain it in Survival by searching for it. Update 0.9.0 added [dungeons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dungeon), which generate mossy cobblestone as part of the walls, which is the traditional source for it on PC.

As of update 0.9.5, mossy cobblestone is finally craftable by combining one cobblestone with one vine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Minecraft Wiki, Moss Stone is unobtainable in MCPE survival.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Moss_Stone